# Sqlite where in query not working?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using following query

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM  DATA   where Subgroup IN (?) and Indicator=? and Unit=? ", new String[]{subgroup, indicator, unit});
```

subgroup is  like " 'xyz','abc' ". and indicator and unit are strings ,but the query is not retrning any value even if its present in the table.Is there another way to query in Sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part-1** you need to provide placeholders (?) for the `IN` based on number of items in `subgroup`, so if you have 3 items in subgroup, and 2 for `Indicator` and `Unit` that makes the query looks like this:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM  DATA   where Subgroup IN (?,?,?) and Indicator=? and Unit=? ", new String[]{subgroup, indicator, unit});
```

**Part-2** you can't use `subgroup` with comma separated, it has to be an array.
so you need 1 big array which length equals (count of subgroup items, + 2) and merge all parameter values in that array.

again the query will look like this (assume all params are merged into array `oneBigArrayOfParams`) :

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM  DATA   where Subgroup IN (?,?,?) and Indicator=? and Unit=? ", oneBigArrayOfParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its the correct way but i used the following statement and its working.

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM  DATA   where Subgroup IN ("+subgroup+") and Indicator=? and Unit=? ", new String[]{ indicator, unit});

Comment: this will work if the values are numeric otherwise they have to be wrapped in `'` Plus, this is not how to use prepared statement... also some security issue might be here (Sql Injection) although it's not exposed as in a web site, but it could be a bad practice on minimum ?